# Error in grub [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, system, grub

after installing Elementary OS , reboot my laptop ( To start running the operating system supposedly) and I get a black screen with this message:

---

> [ Minimal BASH -like line editing is supported. for the first word ,
>   TAB lists possible command completions . Anywhere else TAB lists the
>   possible completions of a device / filename . ]

---

Actually I am a rookie , but I'm sure I did everything right . In fact , I could successfully install and run Ubuntu .

I really hope your help,
Thank you

Comment: Ubuntu ? Is it dual boot ? What are the OS in your system?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem  use this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows),

1. Boot from live USB
2. Identify the partition of elementary OS
3. Open terminal and run the commands:

   (Replace `sda2` with your partition )

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
   sudo chroot /mnt
   update-grub
   ```

   If you got errors then (this is optional):

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   update-grub
   ```

   Finally ;

   ```
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```

Alternatively:

- Either from an Ubuntu live-session  or from your installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

<sub>reference [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)</sub>