# i can't boot elemntary os freya "minimal BASH like line editing is supported"

Tags: boot, grub

I decided to leave windows and use Linux, but I have a problem - when I installed elementary OS I couldn't boot, a black screen appeared and says "minimal BASH like line editing is supported..." and that is it.

I tried to use boot-repair in a live USB, but it didn't work, [here is the info that boot-repair shows me](http://paste2.org/g0MBjjkE).

[I've tried both of these](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/error-in-grub-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-for) but nothing works, can anyone help me please??

Comment: In the link answer, which method you followed?

Comment: HAVE you tried disabling safe boot and UEFI?

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot from the Live CD
2. Open `gparted` → Right Click on `sda1` → Flags: Check `boot`, quit
3. Open terminal
4. Mount partitions

   ```
   mkdir ~/efi
   mkdir ~/root
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 ~/efi/
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 ~/root/
   ```
5. Reinstall `grub`

   ```
   sudo grup-install --efi-directory=/home/elementary/efi/ --root-directory=/home/elementary/root/ /dev/sda
   ```
6. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing Freya.  I think I solved it by starting boot-repair from a live USB, then opening the advanced options.

I think I unchecked "Restore EFI Backups" and made sure "Reinstall Grub" and "Purge GRUB before reinstalling it were checked"

I was then able to boot.  There were lots of GRUB menu items so I installed GRUB customizer and used it to edit the GRUB menu.

I hope this helps.

Jay